# Regex for File and Symbol Remove?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following `regex`

```
/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
```

Which works for `fileNames` in ensuring on `gif`, `jpeg` and `png`'s are accepted. However, I want to extend this code to also check `fileNames` and ensure they don't contain `dangerous` characters like

```
!@#$%^&*()
```

1. How can I do this ?
2. How can I "replace" these with "" ?

Comment: Good source for learning regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript string replace with regex to strip off illegal characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780696/javascript-string-replace-with-regex-to-strip-off-illegal-characters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to only allow a specific set of characters instead of denying every possible dangerous character, as you possibly don't know all possible dangerous characters. You know, however, all the characters you want to allow.

Use this:

```
/^\w+(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
```

This ensures that the filename contains only non-dangerous characters (letter, numbers and _).

You could also remove not allowed characters:

```
name = name.replace(/[^\w.]+/g, '')
```

Comment: Actually it works with brackets ? `/[^\w]+(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i`

Comment: no, the `^` as the begining matches the begining of the string. The `\w` means *letters, numbers and _* (like [a-zA-Z_]).

Comment: hmm on image strings it doesn't appear to be working for me ? the square brackets blocks everything and without them - it allows invalid filenames ?

Comment: what kind of invalid filename does it allow ? try it here http://jsfiddle.net/gZ2cD/

Comment: it seems to be working via http://regexpal.com/ with `/(^\w+)(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i`

Answer (score 0):

This regex will only match if none of the undesired characters are present

```
/^[^!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)]*$/
```

Answer (score 0):

I would actually do this separately; first use the regex to ensure the proper extension, and then plain old `indexOf` on each character to test for it in the string. However, you can also use a lookahead, which JavaScript supports:

```
/^(?!.*[!@#$%^&*()]).*(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
```