# Replace illegal character in javascript string with the legal one

Tags: javascript, replace, character

how do I replace illegal character in a javascript code? I found a lot of solution to strip them off the string but none to actually keep the char there.

here an example line:

```
document.getElementById("popupcontent").innerHTML += "<img class='popupbanner' src='" + eventcontent[date][i]['bannerimg'] + "' />";
```

So in my function, it make my "for" loop not working properly as soon as the following char are in a string: <, >, /

any help is appreciated.

regards,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript string replace with regex to strip off illegal characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780696/javascript-string-replace-with-regex-to-strip-off-illegal-characters)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escaping HTML strings with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace characters in javascript using the `replace()` function. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780696/javascript-string-replace-with-regex-to-strip-off-illegal-characters) stackoverflow post.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the browser automatically escape the stuff for you:

```
function escape(string) {
    var target = document.createElement('div');
    target.appendChild(document.createTextNode(string));
    return target.innerHTML;
}
```

---

Then use it by:

```
var escapedString = escape(eventcontent[date][i]['bannerimg']);
document.getElementById("popupcontent").innerHTML += "<img class='popupbanner' src='" + escapedString + "' />";
```