# Regex to remove specific special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How can I remove specific special characters from a string using regex in JavaScript?

1. single quotes `'`
2. double quotes `"`
3. ampersand `&`
4. registered `®`
5. trademark `™`

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What effort have you made to solve this yourself before asking here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript string replace with regex to strip off illegal characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780696/javascript-string-replace-with-regex-to-strip-off-illegal-characters)

Comment: with the code i tried, i was not able to successfully replace reg and trademark

Comment: Anyways, add your code @user3465554.

Comment: *"with the code i tried, i was not able to successfully replace reg and trademark"* - So if you *were* able to replace the other characters there was no need to include them in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `string.replace()` method and the [unicode escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) for your special characters. You have to use the `\` character to [escape in JavaScript regex](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp)

```
var str = 'Here is a \' string \" with \" \' some @ special ® characters ™ & &'
str.replace(/['"\u0040\u0026\u2122\u00ae]/g, '')
```

`/pattern/` denotes a regex pattern in JavaScript

`[charset]` says which set of characters to match

`/g` specifies global matches so it will replace all occurrences

Comment: You don't need to escape `'` or `"` in a regex.

Answer (score -1):

```js
console.info(`a'b"c&d®e™f`.replace(/['"&®™]/g, ''));
```